# HERE Maps SDK iOS Swift 4 turn by turn navigation - onscreen information

Tags: swift, navigation, here-api

I made a transition from Mapbox to Here Maps.

I took the below linked github code as reference. Turn by turn navigation works but I only get voice information. There is no UI element on the screen to display info as Mapbox prodives.

Is there a way to enable turn by turn UI?

[github example project page](https://github.com/Chinese-Dragon/HereMap/blob/a8ea4c522622f2fa25576cc475f43cdd4130cb44/HEREMapPractice/MapViewController.swift)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the official turn-by-turn navigation example from
the [heremaps](https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/tree/master/turn-by-turn-navigation-ios) github?  Though it's an ObjectiveC rather than a Swift example it may have clues for what you are looking for:
https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/tree/master/turn-by-turn-navigation-ios

Comment: Are you using the Premium iOS SDK?  https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics/map-guidance.html

Comment: Yes, I am using premium SDK.

Comment: In General the HERE SDK does not provide any out of box UI components, there are corresponding methods in the SDK to get the requirement informaiton and it is upto the app developer to develop the UI as per their requirement. As an alternative there is a UI Kit available from HERE which provides a simple UI on top of the HERE Premium SDK, latest UI Kit links available in the release notification  (https://developer.here.com/blog/august-2018-release-highlights)

Comment: Thanks for the info...

Answer (score 0):

Summary: In general the HERE SDK does not provide any out of box UI components, there are corresponding methods in the SDK to get the requirement information and it is up to the app developer to develop the UI as per their requirement. As an alternative there is a UI Kit available from HERE which provides a simple UI on top of the HERE Premium SDK, latest UI Kit links available in the release notification (https://developer.here.com/blog/august-2018-release-highlights)